# Clone current host OS to a guest virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I would like to run a few repeated checks on a setup procedure I am documenting, to verify my document.  I would like to somehow create a VM that replicates the environment on my machine, i.e. the host machine, onto a guest VM.  Then I can use Windows' System Restore on the guest to start at the point before I commenced the setup procedure and repeat it as many times as required until no more trial-and-error etc. is required to supplement my document.

I have Virtual PC and VirtualBox available to install as host environments, running on Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article [VirtualBox P2V Success](http://blog.subaquatic.net/archives/virtualbox-p2v-success/) for how to convert a Windows machine to VirtualBox by using the [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/download/converter/).

Another possibility is [Paragon Backup & Recovery (Advanced) Free](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/), using the P2V Migration wizard, which can, according to the documentation, convert any partition to a VM.

Comment: I've finally tried this, but I get a startup error on the guest box.  I'll follow up and report back.

Comment: Added another possibility.

Comment: @ProfKaos: which one works for you?

Comment: @pistaloper I'm no longer using Virtual Box but VMWare Player, and its cousin VMWare vCenter Converter does a beautiful job.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility: [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415).